# Daala - Implementing intra_paint.c as a video encoder

Tags: c, video, encoding, effect

I've been looking at rendering visual effects lately and I stumbled across this: https://people.xiph.org/~jm/daala/paint_demo/

It's an effect I really like and I'd like to implement it as a command line tool where I can pass in a video (in .ogv or .y4m format as per the examples in the git or any other format to be honest).

So I've cloned: https://github.com/jmvalin/daala/commits/exp_paint_deringing4 and extracted it and from what I understand I need to be looking at the intra_paint.c and intra_paint_enc.c files but I'm not sure how to implement them into a command line tool similar to the encoder_example.c file in the examples directory. I imagine it would be pretty simple but I'm pretty new to this and I can't really see how to do it.

Could anybody point me in the right direction as to what I should be attempting to do to utilise this?